# Is there a good way to produce documentation for swig interfaces?

Tags: python, documentation, swig

I'd like to know if there are any good techniques for constructing/maintaining
documentation on the interface.

I'm building an interface from c++ code to python using swig; mostly I'm just
%including the c++ header files.  I'm dealing with at least dozens of classes
and 100's of functions, so automated tools are preferred.

Ideally, I'd like to use the doxygen formatted comments in the c++ headers to
populate the docstrings in the python classes/methods.

Alternately, generating separate documentation (in ascii, html...)
would also be useful.  It looks like this kind of functionality was supported
in earlier versions of swig (1.3 and earlier) but I don't see a way to do
it with 2.0.

Are there any useful (automated) techniques for documenting the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some mileage in [`%feature("autodoc")`](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn67) with SWIG 2.0, which I think is as far is it goes currently.

For example:

```
%module test

%feature("autodoc", "3");

void foo (int *a, void *bar, double epsilon);
```

causes some vaguely sane documentation to be inserted.

If that isn't sufficient I think the next easiest step would be to use [`%pythonprepend`](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn42) to make a marker that's unique enough `sed` or similar can be used to insert documentation into the interface after SWIG has run automatically:

```
%pythonprepend foo "MARKER"
```

and then:

```
sed -ei 's/MARKER/some documentation' test.py
```

Where you could find the functions to `%pythonprepend` by looking over the Doxygen output using a (Python?) script to generate the markers and substitute them after running SWIG.

Comment: For anyone looking at this years later and wondering how to accomplish the same thing, SWIG 4 supports the `-doxygen` flag to automatically read Doxygen-style comments in header files, translate them to Pydoc or Javadoc, and include them in the SWIG-generated sources. I was able to incorporate it into my workflow by simply changing `swig -c++ -python -o <...>` to `swig -c++ -python -doxygen -o <...>` in my Makefile, and now my SWIG-generated .py files have Pydoc comments.

Answer (score 9):

To get your doxygen comments into the python files there exists a python tool called doxy2swig.py on the web as described [here](http://www.enricozini.org/2007/tips/swig-doxygen-docstring/).

Create xml documentation from your code. Then use the tool:

> doxy2swig.py index.xml documentation.i

and import documentation.i in you swig interface file via

> %import "documentation.i"

And its done.

Comment: link to doxy2swig.py http://svn.cc.gatech.edu/graphs/stinger/tags/v2013-08-27/python/doxy2swig.py

Comment: I started an [improved version of doxy2swig.py](https://github.com/m7thon/doxy2swig).

Comment: For anyone looking at this years later and wondering how to accomplish the same thing, SWIG 4 supports the `-doxygen` flag to automatically read Doxygen-style comments in header files, translate them to Pydoc or Javadoc, and include them in the SWIG-generated sources. I was able to incorporate it into my workflow by simply changing `swig -c++ -python -o <...>` to `swig -c++ -python -doxygen -o <...>` in my Makefile, and now my SWIG-generated .py files have Pydoc comments.